# $.ajax post array as Json to PHP. $_POST = empty

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Ok, I spend many time on this, I don't get what I'm doing wrong.

**It seems impossible to get the data in the PHP file**.

1. First I call many times "copy" to fill the "result" array.
2. Then, I call the `$.ajax` method
3. In the process.php $_POST is empty

*--> In the PHP `$x`, `$y` or `$time` or not null but not empty.*

> **Edit 2:**
>
> Ok - with json_last_error() i saw that it's my json which is
>   "Syntax error: malformed". But i don't know how to encode it better than what i'm
>   doing.
>
> **So i cheat by adding a stripslashes() on the $_POST.**
>
> [{\"x\":104,\"y\":218,\"timestamp\":1349476537434},{\"x\":90,\"y\":202,\"timestamp\":1349476537469},{\"x\":82,\"y\":192,\"timestamp\":1349476537487},{\"x\":71,\"y\":177,\"timestamp\":1349476537514},{\"x\":68,\"y\":174,\"timestamp\":1349476537568},{\"x\":68,\"y\":173,\"timestamp\":1349476537801},{\"x\":68,\"y\":174,\"timestamp\":1349476538478},{\"x\":68,\"y\":175,\"timestamp\":1349476538512},{\"x\":68,\"y\":175,\"timestamp\":1349476538579},{\"x\":69,\"y\":175,\"timestamp\":1349476538678}]
>
> **Edit 1:**
>
> **The posted data seems to be good (look under), and i finish in the
>   "success function".**
>
> [{"x":529,"y":97,"time":1349469608703},{"x":385,"y":331,"time":1349469608720},.....]

**JS Side - index.php :**

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>    

results = new Array();

function copy(x, y, time) {
   var o = { 'x': x, 'y': y, 'time': time };
   results.push(o);
}

function save() {
    var encoded_results = JSON.stringify(results);

    $.ajax({
        url: "process.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            "results" : encoded_results 
        },

        success: function(data, status, xhr) {
           alert(data);
           console.log(data);
           console.log(xhr);
        },      
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
}
```

**PHP Side - process.php :**

```
if(isset($_POST["results"]))
{
    $result_json = $_POST["results"];
    $JSONArray  = json_decode($result_json, true);

    if($JSONArray !== null)
    { 
        $x = $JSONArray["x"];
        $y = $JSONArray["y"];
        $time = $JSONArray["time"]
    }
}
```

Comment: looks like your results = new Array; should be results = new Array();

Comment: What does Firebug show you is being passed to the server?

Comment: What is the actual issue you face?

Comment: GwynHowell copy / paste mistake - Corrected, thanks.
PaulTomblin just added those informations - look edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the JavaScript side you are posting an array of objects - a list of x / y / time combinations. The PHP side however ignores the list and object part:

```
$x = $JSONArray["x"];
```

vs.

```
$x = $JSONArray[0]->x;
```

So overall in a loop maybe:

```
foreach($JSONArray as $triple)
{
    $x=$triple->x;
    $y=$triple->y;
    $time=$triple->time;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$JSONArray` is an arrray of associative arrays, so to access first element f it use `$JSONArray[0]['x]`, `$JSONArray[0]['y']` instead of `$JSONArray['x']`

Answer (score 0):

Also set the dataType: attribute

`dataType : 'json'`   in your ajaxrequest

Comment: I tryed, i don't know why but this is creating an error. 
"SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier".

Answer (score 0):

I've just done this, this is my syntax for the AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "test2.php",
  data: { anarray : array1 },
  dataType: "json",
  success:function(result){  
  array1 = result;
  $.each(array1, function(x, valu){
    $('#arraycontent').hide().append(x + " " + valu + "<br>").fadeIn();
  })
    }            
    });
```

And the PHP file simple pushed 2 elements for demonstration:

```
<?php 
$testArray = $_REQUEST['anarray'];

array_push($testArray, 'test', 'stuff');

echo json_encode($testArray);

?>
```